# Grammar not parsing as expected with negative lookaround assertion

Tags: grammar, raku

OK, this is either a bug or I'm going to look like a total idiot and I'm using a lookaround assertion completely wrong. I don't care about the latter so here we go.

Got this grammar I'm testing:

```
our grammar HC2 {
        token TOP { <line>+ }
        token line { [ <header> \n | <not-header> \n ] }
        token header { <header-start> <header-content> }
        token not-header { \N* }
        token header-start { <header-one> }
        token header-one { <[#]> <![#]> } # note this negative lookahead here
        token header-content { \N* }
}
```

I want to capture a markdown header with just one `#` sign, no more.

Here is the output from Grammar::Tracer/Debugger:

[image]

So it's skipping right over the `<header-start>` capture. If I remove the `<![#]>` negative lookahead assertion, I get this:

[image]

So is this a bug or am I out to lunch?

As text:

```
TOP
> 
|  line
> 
|  |  not-header
> 
|  |  * MATCH "# Grandmother's for a Brighter Future"
> 
|  * MATCH "# Grandmother's for a Brighter Future\n"
> 
|  line
> 
|  |  not-header
> 
|  |  * MATCH ""
> 
|  * MATCH "\n"
> 
|  line
> 
|  |  not-header
> 
|  |  * MATCH "# Development site"
> 
|  * MATCH "# Development site\n"
> 
|  line
> 
|  |  not-header
> 
|  |  * MATCH "* The new site is up and running at example.com"
> 
|  * MATCH "* The new site is up and running at example.com\n"
> 
|  line
> 
|  |  not-header
> 


TOP
> 
|  line
> 
|  |  header
> 
|  |  |  header-start
> 
|  |  |  |  header-one
> 
|  |  |  |  * MATCH "#"
> 
|  |  |  * MATCH "#"
> 
|  |  |  header-content
> 
|  |  |  * MATCH " Grandmother's for a Brighter Future"
> 
|  |  * MATCH "# Grandmother's for a Brighter Future"
> 
|  * MATCH "# Grandmother's for a Brighter Future\n"
> 
|  line
> 
|  |  not-header
> 
|  |  * MATCH ""
> 
|  * MATCH "\n"
> 
|  line
> 
|  |  header
> 
|  |  |  header-start
> 
|  |  |  |  header-one
> 
|  |  |  |  * MATCH "#"
> 
|  |  |  * MATCH "#"
```

**UPDATE:** If I modify `header-start` to:

`token header-one { <[#]> <-[#]> }`

it matches as expected. However, that does not answer the question as to why the original code does not match.

Comment: Please post your output as text, rather than images of text.

Comment: added textual output

Comment: OK, seems that my question is a dupe of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62686065/using-after-as-lookbehind-in-a-grammar-in-raku

Comment: Checkout results of `say m/ 'a' <![a]> \N* |  (\N*) / for 'a', 'ab', 'abc'; say m/ 'a' <![a]> \N* || (\N*) / for 'a', 'ab', 'abc';`. [Google for "declarative prefix"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22declarative+prefix%22). I have to go to sleep now.

Comment: @raiph you are a madman, in a good way.

Comment: There ARE issues with lookarounds, see: "Lookaround regex and character consumption" https://stackoverflow.com/q/69004383/7270649

Comment: I've rewritten my regex to get rid of them and do things in a cleaner way.

Answer (score 5):

OK, so the non-technical answer is I made a bad assumption that the `|` character behaves the same was as in Perl. It does not. In Perl, the regex engine attempts to match the pattern on the left hand side of the `|` character. If that fails, it moves on to the pattern in the right hand side.

To get the "old school" Perl behavior, use the `||` operator, called the "Alternation" operator: [https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Alternation:_||](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Alternation:_%7C%7C)

The `|` operator is called the "Longest Alternation" operator. See [https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Longest_alternation:_|](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Longest_alternation:_%7C)

A more detailed, much more technical discussion of how the "Longest Alternation" operator works is here: https://design.raku.org/S05.html#Longest-token_matching

Though I was already aware the `||` existed from my reading of the docs, I didn't read about it carefully. I mistakenly assumed Raku core developer would make `|` behave like it did in Perl and that `||` was some cool new operator I could learn about later.

Big takeaway: try hard to uncover the basic assumptions you are making and don't assume anything until you've read the docs closely.

Comment: Seems like this difference between Perl and Raku should be noted here: https://docs.raku.org/language/5to6-perlop

Comment: The behavior is buried on this long page of "Traps": https://docs.raku.org/language/traps#|_vs_||:_which_branch_will_win